# Приложение не работает на Android 4.0.x

Tags: java, android, android-studio, activity

На версиях Android 5.x.x и выше приложение отлично работает, а на версии 4.0.х не запускается.
В чем может быть причина?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.os.Vibrator;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import java.util.Random;
 import static android.content.Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED;
 import static android.content.Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED;
import static android.content.Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK;
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
SharedPreferences sPref;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRequestedOrientation ( ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED );
    requestWindowFeature ( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView ( R.layout.activity );
    if (getSupportActionBar () != null) {
        getSupportActionBar ().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled ( false );
    }
    getSupportActionBar ().hide ();
    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView ( R.layout.activity );
    final Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService ( Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE );
    final ImageButton cardbutton = findViewById ( R.id.cardbutton );
    final TextView infotext = findViewById ( R.id.infotext );
    final ImageButton mebiusbutton = findViewById ( R.id.mebius );
    final TextView version = findViewById ( R.id.version );
    final TextView byGuahoo = findViewById ( R.id.byGuahoo );
    final ImageButton arrowbutton = findViewById ( R.id.arrow );
    final ImageView title = findViewById ( R.id.titleView );
    byGuahoo.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
    version.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
    infotext.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
    mebiusbutton.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
    arrowbutton.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
    //final Animation rotate_card = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation ( this, R.anim.rotate_card );
    infotext.setMovementMethod ( new ScrollingMovementMethod () );
    sPref = getApplicationContext ().getSharedPreferences ( "drawableId", MODE_PRIVATE );
    final int[] imageIds = {
            R.drawable.n00,
            R.drawable.n01,
            R.drawable.n02,
            R.drawable.n03,

    };
    final String[] texts = {
            getString ( R.string.n00 ),
            getString ( R.string.n01 ),
            getString ( R.string.n02 ),
            getString ( R.string.n03 ),

    };
    if (sPref.contains ( "drawableId" )) {
        final int drawableId = sPref.getInt ( "drawableId", 0 );
        String textId = sPref.getString ( "textId", "" );
        //infotext.setBackgroundColor ( Color.parseColor ( "#ffffff" ) );
        cardbutton.setImageResource ( drawableId );
        infotext.setText (Html.fromHtml( textId ));
        infotext.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
        version.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
        byGuahoo.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
        mebiusbutton.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
        arrowbutton.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
        title.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );

        cardbutton.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                infotext.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
                mebiusbutton.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
                arrowbutton.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
                title.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
                cardbutton.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
            }
        } );
    } else {
        cardbutton.setTag ( 1 );
        cardbutton.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int status = (Integer) v.getTag ();
                if (status == 1) {

                    Random generator = new Random ();
                    int index = generator.nextInt ( imageIds.length );
                    int randomImageId = imageIds[index];
                    String text = texts[index];
                    cardbutton.setImageResource ( randomImageId );
                    infotext.setText (Html.fromHtml ( text ));
                    sPref = getApplicationContext ().getSharedPreferences ( "drawableId", MODE_PRIVATE );
                    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit ();
                    ed.putInt ( "drawableId", imageIds[index] );
                    ed.putString ( "textId", texts[index] );
                    ed.apply ();
                    //infotext.setBackgroundColor ( Color.parseColor ( "#ffffff" ) );
                    infotext.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
                    version.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
                    byGuahoo.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
                    mebiusbutton.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
                    arrowbutton.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
                    title.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
                    //vibrator.vibrate ( 100 );
                    v.setTag ( 0 );
                } else {
                    infotext.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
                    mebiusbutton.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
                    arrowbutton.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
                    title.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
                    cardbutton.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
                    v.setTag ( 0 );
                }
            }
        } );
    }
    mebiusbutton.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
                                          @Override
                                          public void onClick(View r) {
                                              sPref = getApplicationContext ().getSharedPreferences ( "drawableId", MODE_PRIVATE );
                                              SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit ();
                                              ed.clear ();
                                              ed.apply ();
                                              Intent i = getBaseContext ().getPackageManager ()
                                                      .getLaunchIntentForPackage ( getBaseContext ().getPackageName () );
                                              assert i != null;
                                              i.addFlags ( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
                                              finish ();
                                              startActivity ( i );
                                          }
                                      }
    );
    arrowbutton.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            {
                final TextView infotext = findViewById ( R.id.infotext );
                ImageButton mebiusbutton = findViewById ( R.id.mebius );
                final TextView version = findViewById ( R.id.version );
                final TextView byGuahoo = findViewById ( R.id.byGuahoo );
                final ImageView title = findViewById ( R.id.titleView );
                byGuahoo.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
                version.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
                infotext.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
                mebiusbutton.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
                title.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
                arrowbutton.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
                cardbutton.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
            }
        }


    } );
}
```

}

---

Лог выдает большое количество ошибок. Может что-то глобально не подходит для Android 4.0.x?

```
18:19:52.374 3171-3171/com.example.guahoo.tarotoftheday17 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:524)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:499)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1940)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:85)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:73)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:69)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:202)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:122)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:668)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.example.guahoo.tarotoftheday17.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:63)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Проще и разумнее всего посмотреть причину в логах.

Comment: А как посмотреть логи запущенного эмулятора?
В Sdk у меня отображаются только логи приложения/компилятора

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat

Comment: Спасибо,вы мне помогли

Answer (score 1):

Ну, судя по логу, у вас в `AppCompatImageButton` устанавливается большой `Drawable` и при попытке выделения под него памяти приложение падает. Я бы даже сказал, что оно может падать на любой версии андроида при маленьком количестве свободной оперативной памяти.

У вас, возможно, картинка там в большом разрешении.

Comment: Интересно, проверю